# Software or website for live 2D countour plots?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I'm looking for a software tool to plot live contour plots.

With ***live*** I mean something like [Desmos](http://desmos.com), where you can enter formulas with parameters, and then adjust the parameters interactively (with a slider).

With ***coutour plot*** I mean something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can probably do it easily in Mathematica and turn it into an Interactive Demonstration that can be played with the free CDF player.

Comment: Sounds great. Do you have a link to some documentation about the features involved? I know how to create a basic contour plot in Mathematica, but I have no idea how to make it interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it easily in Mathematica and turn it into an interactive demonstration that can be played with the free CDF player.

For examples, see the [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/), which includes source code for many examples. The example below should get you started:

- [Graph and Contour Plots of Functions of Two Variables](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GraphAndContourPlotsOfFunctionsOfTwoVariables/)

These pages should help you get started with CDF:

- [Getting Started with the Computable Document Format (CDF)](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/authoring-cdf/getting-started-with-cdf.html)
- [Create a Computable Document Format (CDF) File](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html)

Comment: If you need help coding this, ask in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.